# Cleanest solution for extracting a specific index from a path

Tags: javascript

If I have a path of an object:

```
const carPath = "data.factories[0].categories[0].cars[0]";
```

What's the cleanest way to extract factory index, category index and car index? The way I managed to do it is by:

```
const factoryIndex = carPath.match(/data.factories\[(\d+)\]/)[1]
const categoryIndex = carPath.match(/categories\[(\d+)\]/)[1]
const carIndex = carPath.match(/cars\[(\d+)\]/)[1]
```

I just take the second value which is captured by `(\d+)`.

Is it possible to target a specific index inside the square brackets with using a global flag so that it returns only one value, which is the index? Or maybe there's even another way?

My scribbles: https://jsfiddle.net/fa4c0myg/1/

Dummy data:

```
{
    data: {
        factories: [
            {
                name: "Factory1",
                categories: [
                    {
                        name: "Category1",
                        cars: [
                            {name: "Car1"}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single regular expression that captures all of those indicies would work.

```js
const carPath = "data.factories[5].categories[6].cars[7]";
const [, // ignore the whole match - only use the capture groups
  factoryIndex,
  categoryIndex,
  carIndex,
] = carPath.match(/data\.factories\[(\d+)\]\.categories\[(\d+)\]\.cars\[(\d+)\]/);
console.log(factoryIndex, categoryIndex, carIndex);
```

Or, if there aren't any other numbers, just:

```js
const carPath = "data.factories[5].categories[6].cars[7]";
const [
  factoryIndex,
  categoryIndex,
  carIndex,
] = carPath.match(/\d+/g);
console.log(factoryIndex, categoryIndex, carIndex);
```

If the match might not exist, test for whether the match failed before extracting from the result first.

```
const match = carPath.match(/...)
if (!match) {
  // error
} else {
  // extract from match
}
```

Comment: Probably worth noting the error that will be thrown on no match, and the importance of the leading comma in the destructuring pattern.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to extract the individual indexes without relying on the order of the returned values (e.g. using the global flag), but these destructuring approaches might be useful for someone as well. If no one else has a better response, I'll accept this one.

Comment: @gfels You could do something like
`(\w+)\[(\d+)\]` so that you have the array property name in one group and the index in the other